# Sort a list of hungarian strings in the hungarian alphabetical order

Tags: java, collation, comparator

I am working at the moment with some data in hungarians.
I have to sort a list of hungarians strings.

According to [this Collation Sequence page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collating_sequence)

> Hungarian alphabetic order is: A=Á, B, C, CS, D, DZ, DZS, E=É, F, G,
>   GY, H, I=Í, J, K, L, LY, M, N, NY, O=Ó, Ö=Ő, P, Q, R, S, SZ, T, TY,
>   U=Ú, Ü=Ű, V, W, X, Y, Z, ZS

So vowels are treated the same (A=Á, ...) so in the result you can have some like that using [Collator](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/Collator.html) :

```
Abdffg
Ádsdfgsd
Aegfghhrf
```

Up to here, no problem :)

But now, I have the requirement to sort according to the [Hungarian alphabet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_alphabet)

> A Á B C Cs D Dz Dzs E É F G Gy H I Í J K L Ly M N Ny O Ó Ö Ő P (Q) R S
>   Sz T Ty U Ú Ü Ű V (W) (X) (Y) Z Zs

A is considered different than Á

Playing with the [Strength](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/Collator.html#setStrength%28int%29) from `Collator` doesnt change the order in the output. A and Á are still mixed up.

Is there any librairies/tricks to sort a list of string according to the hungarian alphabetical order?

So far what I am doing is :

- Sort with `Collator` so that the C/Cs, D,DZ, DZS... are sorted correctly
- Sort again by comparing the first characters of each word based on a map

This looks too much hassle for the task no?

```
List<String> words = Arrays.asList(
        "Árfolyam", "Az",
        "Állásajánlatok","Adminisztráció",
        "Zsfgsdgsdfg", "Qdfasfas"

);

final Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
      map.put("A",0);
      map.put("Á",1);
      map.put("E",2);
      map.put("É",3);

      map.put("O",4);
      map.put("Ó",5);
      map.put("Ö",6);
      map.put("Ő",7);

      map.put("U",8);
      map.put("Ú",9);
      map.put("Ü",10);
      map.put("Ű",11);


      final Collator c = Collator.getInstance(new Locale("hu"));
      c.setStrength(Collator.TERTIARY);
      Collections.sort(words, c);

      Collections.sort(words, new Comparator<String>(){
          public int compare(String s1, String s2) {

              int f = c.compare(s1,s2);
              if (f == 0) return 0;

              String a = Character.toString(s1.charAt(0));
              String b = Character.toString(s2.charAt(0));

              if (map.get(a) != null && map.get(b) != null) {
                  if (map.get(a) < map.get(b)) {
                      return -1;
                  }
                  else if (map.get(a) == map.get(b)) {
                      return 0;
                  }
                  else {
                      return 1;
                  }
              }


              return 0;
          }
      });
```

Thanks for your input

Comment: I understand you are not looking for "identical" comparison strength (Collator.IDENTICAL), right? In that case I guess A and Á would differ...

Comment: Changing the strength to IDENTICAL still sort the list like A and Á were the same.

Comment: In java 6 when I call `Collections.sort(words)` it orders them per your needs with `A` then `Á`...

Comment: @maerics. If you add a word starting with 'Z', the order is A->Z->Á and I would like to have it as A->Á->Z. Sorry I will add more words to the example

Comment: I might be very, very late to the party, but I feel the need to point out that the Hungarian alphabetical order is much more complicated than that. None of the answers on this page handle double digraphs, for example ("ccs" is handled as "cs" + "cs"). [Here is](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/75370/hungarian-alphabetical-order) a short summary of the rules. And even that summary is simplified, because you need a vocabulary to properly sort Hungarian words, because in some exceptional cases the ordering depends on the *meaning* of the word.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found a good idea, you can use a RuleBasedCollator.

Source: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/text/rule.html

And here is the Hungarian rule:

```
 < a,A < á,Á < b,B < c,C < cs,Cs,CS < d,D < dz,Dz,DZ < dzs,Dzs,DZS 
 < e,E < é,É < f,F < g,G < gy,Gy,GY < h,H < i,I < í,Í < j,J
 < k,K < l,L < ly,Ly,LY < m,M < n,N < ny,Ny,NY < o,O < ó,Ó 
 < ö,Ö < ő,Ő < p,P < q,Q < r,R < s,S < sz,Sz,SZ < t,T 
 < ty,Ty,TY < u,U < ú,Ú < ü,Ü < ű,Ű < v,V < w,W < x,X < y,Y < z,Z < zs,Zs,ZS
```

Comment: Note that it will only work correctly with uppercase strings if you add uppercase versions of the multi-character letters too (eg. cs,Cs,CS).

Comment: Thanks, @T-Gergely. It is fixed.

Comment: Note: You need to watch for doubled digraphs. If a digraph is doubled, only the first "letter" is doubled. 

Therefore, ccs is alphabetically cs + cs, and ssz is alphabetically sz + sz.

Answer (score 2):

By stream you can sort like below:

```
public List<String> sortBy(List<String> sortable) {

  Collator coll = Collator.getInstance(new Locale("hu","HU"));

  return sortable.stream()
                 .sorted(Comparator.comparing(s -> s, coll))
                 .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Will any of the solutions result in ordering the strings (names) 'Czár' and 'Csóka' as Czár, Csóka? This would be the correct order, since CS in Csóka is considered one letter and is after C.
However, recognizing double-character consonants is impossible even with a list of all Hungarian words, since there might be cases, where two words could look exactly the same character by character, but in one there are two consonants together, while in the other there are two characters reprezenting one letter at the very same place.

Answer (score 0):

Change the order of your map.

Put the numeric representation as the key and the letter as the value. This will allow you to use a TreeMap which will be sorted by key.

You can then just do map.get(1) and it will return the first letter of the alphabet.

Comment: With what element will I map the key with? Can you please give an example ? -Thanks